# integration of multiple databases via talend open studio for big data

Tags: business-intelligence

I have 11 MySQL Databases, each one contains 81 tables, each table have the same schema in the 11 databases, my goal is to integrate those databases into a MongoDB database
I'm working with Talend Open Studio for Big Data

Can you please suggest a way that can help me?

Comment: The question is too broad. The actual way how to integrate these data sources into MongoDB depends on what is supposed by "integration"? What is expected final state?

Comment: Bring together those 11 databases in only one database